# Why should my mvc application suddenly getting logout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, web-config

I am facing the issue about sudden logout. Since I specified the proper timeout in my web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="60">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

It is happening when I am clicking on any another menu. I checked in my layout page and respective actions. but somehow session getting down. Why should this is happening ? Even it is happening locally in development environment.

Comment: Session timeout and authentication timeout are different things.  If you are using forms authentication, look for the timeout on the authentication/forms node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Paddy's and Aravindan's answers, the InProc session state provider is completely reliant upon the local server's application pool. This means that your session will expire when the application pool expires. To fix this, you could either set the timeout to happen at low traffic periods or by using  one of the other [session state modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx) so your session state will survive an application pool recycle.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set the session as one min so only your application suddenly got signout.
Please set the session time like 6000 something like below

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="6000">
```